# Setting last N bits in an array

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, bit-manipulation, bitfoo

I'm sure this is fairly simple, however I have a major mental block on it, so I need a little help here!

I have an array of 5 integers, the array is already filled with some data. I want to set the last N *bits* of the array to be random noise.

```
[int][int][int][int][int]

eg. set last 40 bits

[unchanged][unchanged][unchanged][24 bits of old data followed 8 bits of randomness][all random]
```

This is largely language agnostic, but I'm working in C# so bonus points for answers in C#

Comment: First you have to define the order of bits in an int, whether MSB or LSB comes first.

Comment: Whatever the native system order is. Ie, it might be different on different machines and I want to be able to handle that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without any bit-fu in C#:

```
BitArray ba = new BitArray (originalIntArray);
for (int i = startToReplaceFrom; i < endToReplaceTo; i++)
    ba.Set (i, randomValue);
```

Comment: Ah, a bit array, of course! I was all up to my neck in bit foo and didn't think of the obvious

Answer (score 1):

When you XOR any data with random data, the result is random, so you can do this:

```
Random random = new Random();
x[x.Length - 2] ^= random.Next(1 << 8);
x[x.Length - 1] = random.Next(1 << 16);
x[x.Length - 1] ^= random.Next(1 << 16) << 16;
```

For a general solution for any N you can use a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 40; ++i)
{
    x[x.Length - i / 32 - 1] ^= random.Next(2) << (i % 32);
}
```

Note that this calls random more times than necessary, but is simple.

Comment: This is only a solution for the specific example I gave above,not the general case? Besides that, I don't quite understand what you're doing in the last case, why the two sets of randomness for the last index?

Comment: @Martin: First set the lower 16 bits, then set the upper 16 bits.

Comment: Ah, because if you just used the 32 bits from random the msb would never be set thanks to 2s complement?

Comment: @Martin: Yes, if you use random.Next() you can get only 31 random bits because it guarantees only positive values.

Answer (score 0):

In pseudo-Python:

```
N        = 5   # array size
bits     = 40  # for instance
int_bits = 32  # bits in one integer

i = N
while bits > 0:
    value_bits  = min (bits, int_bits)
    bits       -= value_bits
    mask        = (1 << value_bits) - 1

    i -= 1
    array[i] ^= random () & mask
```

Comment: @Martin: To think, this depends on machine endiness.  What exactly do you mean by last bits?

Answer (score 0):

Int32 is 4 bytes or 32 bits.
So you need the last int, and 8 bits extra.

> int lastEightBitsMask = 0x000F + 1;
>   Random rand = new Random();
>   arr[arr.Length - 1] = rand.Next();
>   arr[arr.Length - 2] ^= rand.Next(lastEightBitsMask);

Explanation:
The last element's modification should be pretty clear - if you need the last 40 bits, the last 32 bits are included in that.
The remaining eight bits's modification is bounded above by 0x000F + 1, since rand.Next's argument is an exclusive upper bound, the randoms generated will be no more than that. The remaining bits of the number will stay the same, since 1^0 == 1 and 0^0 == 0.